# ng-repeat does not react to given limitTo or filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive that displays subcategories of a feature list.

Problem is, all items are displayed, regardles of the filters i use for the `ng-repeat`.
I use a filter to only show items with a certain `category_uid` and i also use a `limitTo`.

```
app.directive('featureCategory', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        link: function($scope) {
            $scope.featureCountBuffer = $scope.featureCount;
            $scope.listLength = Object.keys($scope.featureList).length;
        },
        scope: {
            featureList: '=',
            featureCount: '@',
            categoryId: '@'
        },
        template:
            '<li>featureCountBuffer : {{featureCountBuffer}} / listLength {{listLength}} / categoryId {{categoryId}}</li>' +
            '<check-item ng-repeat="feature in featureList | filter:{category_uid:categoryId} | limitTo: featureCountBuffer" feature="feature"></check-item>'
    }
});
```

This shows above 40 items thou it starts with the li element showing featureCountBuffer is 5 andcategory_uid being 1 which only applies to 8 items.

Does anyone see my Mistake here?

The featureList looks like this:

```
{
  "1": {
    "uid": "1",
    "title": "foo",
    "category_uid": "1",
    "checked": false
  },
  "2": {
    "uid": "2",
    "title": "bar",
    "category_uid": "1",
    "checked": false
  },
  "3": {
    "uid": "3",
    "title": "foobar",
    "category_uid": "2",
    "checked": false
  },
  "4": {
    "uid": "4",
    "title": "barfoo",
    "category_uid": "2",
    "checked": false
  },
  "5": {
    "uid": "5",
    "title": "barbar",
    "category_uid": "3",
    "checked": false
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the Problem.

Angulars ng-repeat works with `objects of objects` but the filters do not.
You can either write your own filters to fix this or just use an array of objects.

I used [lodash's](http://lodash.com/docs#toArray) `_.toArray` to convert mine. My Changes:

```
[..]
link: function($scope) {
  [..]
  $scope.featureList = _.toArray($scope.featureList);
},
[..]
```

Youcan read about it in more detail [in this article](http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting this! I found an alternative solution to use the `$index` property:

```
 <ul>                                          
   <li ng-repeat="(id, value) in test" ng-if="$index < 3" >              
   {{ $index }} {{ id }} {{ value }}        
   </li>                                       
 </ul>
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I'll try using it the next time i run into this problem.